# Android studio build application error: protocol fault (couldn't read status)

Tags: android, windows-8.1

I re-downloaded Android Studio (latest version) and installed it. I must precise I had an ancient version which I deleted some months ago (I did not use it anymore).

However, I encounter a problem after installing this new version. When I try to run my blank application, I saw it started the emulator but nothing starts. Indeed in the console, I can read :

```html
error: protocol fault (couldn't read status): No error

'C:\Users\[myname]\Android\sdk\platform-tools\adb.exe start-server' failed -- run manually if necessary
```

I have tried these solutions but none of them worked... :

The command *adb kill-server* and then *adb start-server* give the same output : *error: protocol fault (couldn't read status): No error*

I, of course, tried to restart my computer.

I am running on windows 8.1

Edit:
After the comment of *igor_rb*, I tried : *set ADB_TRACE=all* then *adb kill-server* and *adb start-server*, here are the information

[image]

Comment: try  `set ADB_TRACE=all` in cmd and than run again `adb kill-server` + `adb start-server`. It can helps to find issue.

Comment: I edited the post to add the output, thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Surprinsingly, creating a script which contains the following code and executes each time my computer start solved the problem :

```
adb kill-server
adb start-server
```

I added the script here : C:\Users[name]\AppData\Roaming\Microsoft\Windows\Start Menu\Programs and it runs at each start (before I can open Android Studio)

Answer (score 0):

Possibly, you are use too old version of `adb`.

Try to update it (`Tools` -> `SDK Manager` -> `SDK Tools` tab -> `Android SDK Platform-Tools`)